# Cortex-M0+ timer prescaler is not slowing down TIM2

Tags: c, assembly, timer, stm32, cortex-m

I am trying to measure the performance of some code using the TIM2 timer on the STM32L031K6 (Cortex-M0+).
Because the M0+ only offers 16-bit counters, I want to set the prescaler of TIM2 to count slower. However, it seems to show no effect at all. The timer still runs at maximum speed, which is not desirable for my use case.

I used libopencm3 before, but now I am writing to the registers directly via pointers, because I won't have access to libopencm3 afterwards anyways.
I looked through the datasheet of the STM32L0 series and read how to set up the timers directly. Setting up the timer and measuring some small code code (for loop with nops) works perfectly. But setting the prescaler won't work. I wrote the value (for example 0x1234) to the prescale register and read it again to make sure the write actually worked. I tried to trigger the update event, because it seems some buffering is going on with shadow registers but it also didn't work.

```
void __attribute__ ((noinline)) timer_setup()
{
  *(  (uint32_t*) 0x40021038 ) |= 1; //Enable Timer in RCC_APB1ENR (Bit 0)

  *(  (uint32_t*) 0x40000028 ) = 0x1234; //Some prescaler

  *(  (uint32_t*) 0x4000002C ) = 0xFFFF; //Auto-Reload to max 2**16

  // *(  (uint32_t*) 0x40000000 ) ^= 2; //I tried triggering an update here

  // *(  (uint32_t*) 0x40000014 ) ^= 1; //But it also didn't work

  *(  (uint32_t*) 0x40000000 ) ^= 1; //Enable the timer
}

void __attribute__ ((noinline)) timer_stop()
{
  *(  (uint32_t*) 0x40000000 ) ^= 1; //Stop the timer
}

int __attribute__ ((noinline)) timer_value()
{
  return *(  (uint32_t*) 0x40000024 ); //Read the counter
}
```

I expected that the count is lower if I set a prescaler. However, I always get the same value. For example 1326 for a loop of nops.

Comment: In the reference manual p365 it says: The new prescaler ratio is taken into account at the next update event. Maybe you could look into when an update event is generated, or if you can generate one yourself? I haven't used this controller, Can't give you more info.

Comment: What is it? Do you think that we have the time to decode your magic numbers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to generate an update event, you can do this by setting bit 0 of the timer's `EGR` register.

Your two lines where you've commented "I tried triggering an update here", you're using the `^=` operator, to set bits in a register use `|=` instead.

You should also use the human readable defines provided by ST for the registers and their addresses. This will allow you to write something like `TIM2->EGR |= TIM_EGR_UG;` to generate your update event, much more readable than `*(  (uint32_t*) 0x40000014 ) |= 1;`

Comment: Thanks, I just found the header with the ST defines. Until now I only had one for the M4.
I was able to solve the problem by moving the EGR line under the enable command. After looking closely at the figures in the datasheet, I saw that the update is always triggered after the Enable of the timer.
I my case I prefer the ^= operator, as I know that the XOR won't backfire on me. But I will keep the advice with |= in mind.

Comment: The XOR operator will shoot you in the back waaay harder. Example: Your `timer_stop();` will *start* the timer when just called twice by accident.

Comment: @Trunyx, note also that your casting to access registers wasn't quite right. You forgot `volatile`. Should be, for ex: `*((volatile uint32_t*)0x40021038)`, NOT `*((uint32_t*)0x40021038)`. You really should `#define` registers though. Ex: `#define SOME_REG (*((volatile uint32_t*)0x40021038))`, then `SOME_REG |= 1 << 7` to set bit 7 or whatever it is you need to do. As stated already by others though though, no need to do your own `#define`s: just use the registers already defined for you by ST instead!